# How to convert a column of dict into separate columns in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, split

Here is a sample df, with authid as index. I want to split features into several columns. originally features column was filled with dict.

I tried df['features'].apply(pd.Series) but did not work.

```
authid              features                        
108560005        n_clusters           2.0000
                 inertia             23.4968
                 silhouette           0.9061
                 trend_datapoints   355.0000
                 trend_slope         -0.0010
                 trend_pvalue         0.0615
                 resid_std         1075.9582
123750005        n_clusters           2.0000
                 inertia              0.0682
                 silhouette           0.9961
                 trend_datapoints   355.0000
                 trend_slope          0.0046
                 trend_pvalue         0.0000
                 resid_std           75.8126
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Option 1:
`df = df.reset_index().pivot(index='authid', columns='features', values='value')`
Option 2:
`df.unstack()`

by the way I assumed the third column name as value as you didn't mention in the input sample

Comment: There is not a 3rd column. all of it is under features

Comment: I am not sure how thats possible, I am seeing 2.0 as value for n_clusters feature for the authid - 108560005 , Is that not correct understanding?